# Make ion-select label full width in Ionic v6

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic6

I started a new project in **Ionic v6** and added a simple ***ion-select*** in html like this:

```
<ion-item>
        <ion-select placeholder="Select Option">
            <ion-select-option *ngFor="let o of selectOptions" [value]="o.id">{{o.title}}</ion-select-option>
        </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
```

It appears like this:
[image]

I inspected the generated html and I can see that ion-select is taking full width. But the label part that displays the placeholder or the selected option is not taking full width.
I want the label part to also take full width so the dropdown arrow appears on far right of the parent (ion-item) instead of sticking with the text.

I have tried many options but nothing is working. Element customization in Ionic after v3 has become really confusing. Please help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always keep an eye on the CSS Shadow parts in Ionic Docs for all the components. In case of ion-select you can just edit the container shadow part of ion-select to make it's with 100%. Here is the example of CSS code:

```
ion-select::part(container) {
  width: 100%;
}
```

If you are using SCSS use the following code instead:

```
ion-select {
    &::part(container) {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Simar....I will keep this in mind about the shadow part. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

in v6, give the ion-select a width of 100%.
in v7, there is an attrib called [justify](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select#justification) to help you do this without extra css.